# how to fix "Request method 'DELETE' not supported" Error in spring-boot

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

I'm new in spring boot, I'm working on a REST APP using spring-boot with JDBC, which has to manage contacts (add, delete and update), when I send a DELETE request I have this error : "Request method 'DELETE' not supported", I don't have buttons yet, I'm using 'Restlet Client' chrome extension to test my API.
this is my controller :

```
@RestController
public class ContactRestService  {

@Autowired
private ContactRepository contactRepository ;

@RequestMapping(value = "/contacts/{id}",method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Contact getContact(@PathVariable Long id){
    return contactRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/contacts",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Contact save(@RequestBody Contact contact){
     return contactRepository.save(contact);
}

@DeleteMapping (value = "/contacts/{id}")
public void deleteContact(@PathVariable Long id){
     contactRepository.deleteById(id);

 }
 }
```

Comment: Spring-boot version : 2.1.6

Comment: Please show the delete request payloads.